# PHP __set magic method

Tags: php, getter-setter

I just came across this piece of code, but I can't seem to understand what the body means:

```
public function __set($propName, $propValue)
{
    $this->{$propName} = $propValue;
}
```

what does `$this->{$propName}` do?

Comment: Look it up  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: sorry @KA_lin, my question is not on how to use magic methods, but on what the code does, I can't seem to understand the curly brace

Comment: Ah I understand now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->{$propName}` accesses property named $propName. If `$propName === 'name'` then `$this->{$propName}` is the same as `$this->name`.

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces cause the variable between them to be interpolated.  This can be useful in a variety of places, but in this particular place it's effectively doing this:

```
// if $propName = 'mike';
$this->{$propName} = 'X';
// Results in:
$this->mike = 'X';

// if $propName = 'cart';
$this->{$propName} = 'full';
// Results in:
$this->cart = 'full';

// if $propName = 'version';
$this->{$propName} = 3;
// Results in:
$this->version = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand it better